# pgbouncer with currentSchema

Tags: java, postgresql, pgbouncer

Java application works with two shemas: **public** and **quartz**. And i try connect to shema **quartz** with pgbouncer:

```
jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:6432/test_db?currentSchema=quartz;prepareThreshold=0"
```

But my app failed startup. In logs i see error about table (qrtz_locks) doesn't exist (log follow)[image]

This table exist in shema **quartz**. I think that app ignored my props in jdbc - *?currentSchema=quartz* and connect to public. If i used default postgres connect (port 5432), app works correctly.

How to fix my problem and connect to db via pgbouncer with my schema?

This is pgbouncer.ini config

```
[databases]
; fallback connect string
* = host=10.1.2.2 port=5432

[pgbouncer]
logfile = /var/log/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.pid

listen_addr = *
listen_port = 6432

auth_type = md5
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist
auth_hba_file = /etc/pgbouncer/pb_hba.conf
admin_users = postgres
stats_users = postgres

pool_mode = transaction
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits,search_path
application_name_add_host = 1
max_client_conn = 500
default_pool_size = 15
reserve_pool_size = 10
reserve_pool_timeout = 3

server_lifetime = 300
server_idle_timeout = 120
server_connect_timeout = 5
server_login_retry = 1

query_timeout = 60
query_wait_timeout = 60

client_idle_timeout = 60
client_login_timeout = 60
```

Comment: currentSchema isn't a postgresql connection parameter (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) you'll need to find out what jdbc does to handle that.

Comment: @RichardHuxton this is tomcat parameter

Comment: I created separate user and set search_path to another schema. This is work, but i want use one user for connect db

Comment: Then if you're not prepared to share what your java code is doing you'll have to hope that someone who understands both tomcat and pgbouncer comes along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgbouncer does not support this directly.

You could make your system issue "set search_path=quartz" as the first statement every time a new connection is obtained.  Or you could use the other approach you have already described but didn't like.

Comment: Thnks. I did it the same way

Answer (score 0):

Transaction connection mode pooling may cause the 'currentschema='xxxx'' parameter specified in JDBC to be ineffective, resulting in connections to the default 'public' schema of the database.

The solution is to specify the default login schema for the relevant account.

Using your JDBC example:

```
jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:6432/test_db?currentSchema=quartz;prepareThreshold=0"
```

Modify this string to:

```
jdbc:postgresql://pg_quartz_admin@127.0.0.1:6432/test_db 
 ?currentSchema=quartz;prepareThreshold=0"
```

The added `pg_quartz_admin` is the login account, and it should have the necessary permissions for operations under the `quartz` schema.

Then, use the postgres account to change the default login schema for `pg_quartz_admin`:

```
ALTER ROLE pg_quartz_admin IN DATABASE test_db SET search_path TO quartz;
```

Creating a new account and setting the default login schema might seem like a cumbersome way to manage accounts, but it's currently the best solution I can think of.Hope for a better solution.